# Kubernetes: After port-forwarding, I can access a service via "localhost" but not via "hostname"

Tags: docker, go, networking, kubernetes, portforwarding

For the `main.go` code at the end of this question, I ran the following commands to run it on a `kubernetes` install (on a `PC`):

1. `docker image build -t myID/go-demo:1.2 .`
2. `docker image push myID/go-demo:1.2  # Pushed up to DockerHub`
3. `kubectl run demo2 --image=myID/go-demo:1.2 --port=19999 --labels app=demo2`
4. `kubectl port-forward deploy/demo2 19999:8888`

   `Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:19999 -> 8888
    Forwarding from [::1]:19999 -> 8888`

Then, in another `tmux(1)` terminal, I confirmed the service was `LISTEN`ing:

```
user@vps10$ sudo netstat -ntlp | egrep "Local|19999"
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:19999         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      736786/kubectl      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:19999               :::*                    LISTEN      736786/kubectl
```

But here's my problem, noticing success with `localhost` and failure with `hostname -- vps10`:

```
user@vps10$ curl localhost:19999 # Works.
Hello, 世界

user@vps10$ curl vps10:19999     # Fails.
curl: (7) Failed to connect to vps10 port 19999: Connection refused
```

From the above, the issue appears to be that the service is listening only via the `loopback` interface, and if that's indeed the issue, what do I do to get it to listen on `all interfaces` (or on a `specific interface` that I specify). I'm not a `kubernetes` or `go` expert (this example is from a book actually =:)), so please supply commands if necessary. Thank you in advance!

**HTTP server code**:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, 世界")
}

func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8888", nil))
}
```

Comment: try `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 ...`

Comment: @BurakSerdar Ah, that worked. Thank you. If you would like to answer this, I'll upvote and select yours as the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to kubectl help:

```
 # Listen on port 8888 on all addresses, forwarding to 5000 in the pod
  kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/mypod 8888:5000

  # Listen on port 8888 on localhost and selected IP, forwarding to 5000 in the pod
  kubectl port-forward --address localhost,10.19.21.23 pod/mypod 8888:5000
```

The default is forwarding for localhost only.